# SELECT from multiple tables with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, group-by

I've a got a little problem with multitable query. (RDBMS: Access)

Here is the database schema: (only S_Cards, Books, Authors, Students tables are used in this query)
S_Cards is Student book order (in library).

[image: DB Scheme]

Query:
Select the most popular author(s) among students and the number of this author's books, which were ordered in library.

Although I can get list of orders + authors like this in one query:

```
SELECT 
    Students.FirstName & " " & Students.LastName AS [Student], 
    Books.Name AS [Book], Authors.FirstName & " " & Authors.LastName AS [Author]
FROM 
    Students, 
    Books, 
    S_Cards, 
    Authors
WHERE 
    S_Cards.ID_Student = Students.ID 
AND S_Cards.ID_Book = Books.ID 
AND Books.ID_Author = Authors.ID
ORDER BY Authors.LastName
```

Result (sorry, it's in Russian):

[image: Query result]

I can't figure out, why I can't COUNT and GROUP BY like this:

```
SELECT 
    Students.FirstName & " " & Students.LastName AS [Student], 
    Books.Name AS [Book], 
    COUNT(Authors.FirstName & " " & Authors.LastName) AS [Number of books]
FROM Students, Books, S_Cards, Authors
WHERE 
    S_Cards.ID_Student = Students.ID 
AND S_Cards.ID_Book = Books.ID 
AND Books.ID_Author = Authors.ID
GROUP BY 3
```

I get an error that 'Authors.FirstName & " " & Authors.LastName' is not a part of static function or group.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to do this query without JOIN, only by GROUP BY, SELECT, UNION and how?
2. What's the problem in my 2nd query?

Answer (score 1):

Solution (extracted from [older revision in question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12447392/4)):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Author, COUNT(Book) AS [Number of books] FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Students.FirstName & " " & Students.LastName AS [Student], 
        Books.Name AS [Book], 
        Authors.FirstName & " " & Authors.LastName AS [Author]
    FROM 
        Students, 
        Books, 
        S_Cards, 
        Authors
    WHERE 
        S_Cards.ID_Student = Students.ID AND
        S_Cards.ID_Book = Books.ID AND
        Books.ID_Author = Authors.ID
    ORDER BY Authors.LastName
)
GROUP BY Author
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The string [concatenation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in SQL Server is `+` not `&`. Also, you should group by things that are *not* an aggregate function.

```
SELECT Students.FirstName + ' ' + Students.LastName AS [Student]
     , Books.Name AS [Book]
     , COUNT(Authors.FirstName + ' ' + Authors.LastName) AS [Number of books]
  FROM Students
  JOIN S_Cards
    ON S_Cards.ID_Student = Students.ID
  JOIN BOOKS
    ON S_Cards.ID_Book = Books.ID 
  JOIN Authors
    ON Books.ID_Author = Authors.ID
 GROUP BY Students.FirstName + ' ' + Students.LastName
        , Books.Name
```

Please note that I've changed your query to the standard ANSI join syntax, which makes errors that much harder to make and is a lot easier to read.

Thinking about it, your count seems a little strange. Isn't the number of books `COUNT(Books.ID)`?

Comment: This _assumes_ you're using SQL Server (it looks like it). Please always tag questions with the appropriate RDBMS in future.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I think COUNT(Books.ID) would count number of times some book was ordered. I need to count how many times any books by the author was ordered, not some particular book.

RDBMS is Access.

Answer (score 0):

You must GROUP BY anything that is not part of an aggregate function:

```
SELECT 
    Students.FirstName & " " & Students.LastName AS [Student], 
    Books.Name AS [Book], 
    COUNT(Authors.FirstName & " " & Authors.LastName) AS [Number of books]
FROM Students, Books, S_Cards, Authors
WHERE 
    S_Cards.ID_Student = Students.ID 
AND S_Cards.ID_Book = Books.ID 
AND Books.ID_Author = Authors.ID
GROUP BY Students.FirstName & " " & Students.LastName, 
    Books.Name AS [Book]
```

I suggest you start using explicit rather than implicit joins. There are a better choice for MS Access, for the most part.

```
<...>
FROM Students
INNER JOIN S_Cards
ON Students.ID = S_Cards.ID_Student
```

Or

```
<...>
FROM Students
LEFT JOIN S_Cards
ON Students.ID = S_Cards.ID_Student
```

The query design window will allow you to build your JOIN with the correct syntax. Just drag and drop the join fields from one table to the next and choose the join type you need.